# How can I save the django variable in the cookie for further usage?

Tags: jquery, django

Following is the output JSON data I'm getting when I hit the API,

```
{'test_1': {'test_name': 'FASTING SUGAR', 'results': '121.00', 'units': 'mg%', 'low_range': 70.0, 'high_range': 110.0}}
```

```
  <tbody>
     {% for key, value in data.items %}
      <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>{{ value.test_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.results }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.units }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.low_range }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.high_range }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

I'm getting the `{{ data }}` from the API that I want to save it in the cookie so that I can use the old value of `{{ data }}` to append it with the new one using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the data in a session variable which you retrieve and append into each time you query the api endpoint in your view:

```
data = request.session['data']
# get new data from endpoint
# append new data into data variable
request.session['data'] = data
```

To update your table without refreshing the entire page, this function which is called by ajax could render into a separate template containing just the tbody element. You could use the ajax function to update just the html for just that element in the main page.

There may be better ways to do that, but I have used this method successfully before, hope it helps